# Simple SSH connect open source code with JSch

Tags: android, ssh, client

I am trying to make something from this simple example :

SSH, execute remote commands with Android

i am trying to control my raspberry pi through ssh with simple command execution, everything ok except , it doesn't work! the command i am trying is to make empty text.txt, but when i check on the raspberry, there is no such file created. also tried a sudo reboot command , still doesn't work

Here is my main code:

```
package com.example.thesacredhaven.samplessh;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            executeRemoteCommand("pi","root","192.168.219.178",22);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void executeRemoteCommand(
            String username,
            String password,
            String hostname,
            int port) throws Exception {

        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, 22);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setTimeout(10000);
        session.connect();

        // SSH Channel
        ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
        channel.setCommand("lsusb > /home/pi/test.txt");
        channel.connect();
        channel.disconnect();
    }
}
```

What did I do wrong ? I have no error messages and I don't see any SSH connection on my Linux. is there any library ? or some missing step?